# Undefined method "cmdb_searches_path" for form_for in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an cmdbs_controller.rb inside of which I have index and defined cmdb resource route:

```html
def index
  @cisearch = CmdbSearch.new
end
```

Also I have a cmdb_search model which is the model for search form (empty). In my index.html.erb I want to load form_for like that:

```html
<%= form_for @cisearch, remote:true  do |f| %>
...some code..           
<% end %>
```

I have done such a search for the other page before, but now I get an error:

```html
undefined method `cmdb_searches_path'
```

EDIT:
There is no cmdb_search controller, cmdb_model is created for building search form, it is used temorarily. 
EXAMPLE THAT WORKED:
I did it before like that and it worked:

```html
 #requests_controller.rb
def index
  if !user_signed_in?
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  else 
     @requests = Request.search(params[:search]).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").where("payed = ?", false).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(per_page: 20, page: params[:page])
     @search = Search.new
  end
end
```

Then I have the search model.
Inside requests/index.html.erb I have:

```html
<%= form_for @search, remote: true do |f| %>
  .. some code 
<% end %>
```

The way this works is that I create a search model instance inside requests_controller to be able to create form_for @search. I didn't define any specific routes, only resource ones. This worked before but for this one it isn't working.

Comment: run `rake routes` command in terminal and share output here. Also what is your `routes.rb` & `cmdb_search_controller`??

Comment: have you added routes for cmdb_search?

Comment: @user123, no, i think i only need route for submit action of the form. Becaues i didnt add any specific routes for requests_controller

Comment: you have to add `resources :cmdb_searches`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are rendering your form from the index action, it does not knows about the create action. Modify your form_for as:

```
 form_for @cisearch, :url => your_create_action,remote:true
```

Answer (score 0):

add `resources :cmdb_searches` to your routes.rb